# How to pass a value in php function paramater from a smary html template file

Tags: php, smarty

Please help me how to pass user id from smarty file to a php function parameter

PHP Code listings.php

```
    <?php

require_once "include/include.php";
require_once "classes/online_users.php";
global $config_abs_path;
global $db;
global $post_array;


// Check if user online
$ousers = new online_users();
if ($ousers->isUserOnline($user_id)) {
    $smarty->assign("user_is_online","online");     
}



$db->close();
if($db->error!='') { $db_error = $db->getError(); $smarty->assign('db_error',$db_error); }

$smarty->display('listings.html');
close();
?>
```

Here is the smarty variable that want to pass $ousers->isUserOnline($user_id)
listings.html

```
{$v.user_id}
```

Output i want to show user online/offline

```
{if $user_is_online}
User Online                                             {else}                                          User Offline                                            {/if}
```

Comment: Any way to send back info to php function ...?

Comment: Ew! That code is ugly.

Comment: You should better explain what you want to achieve. For me it's unclear.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to assign $ousers to a smarty variable.

```
$smarty->assign('ousers', $ousers);
```

After that, within your smarty you can run

```
{$ousers->isUserOnline($v.user_id)}
```

So, your final smarty code would look like this:

```
{$user_is_online = $ousers->isUserOnline($v.user_id)}

{if $user_is_online}
  User Online
{else}
  User Offline
{/if}
```

Also, you can cut out the following code entirely, since you don't need it anymore.  You're running the equivalent of this entirely from within smarty now:

```
if ($ousers->isUserOnline($user_id)) {
   $smarty->assign("user_is_online","online");     
}
```

Comment: Then you can simply call the function you need to call from smarty.  Smarty can execute any PHP functions.  I'll edit my answer now.

Comment: It is just displaying id of user.

Comment: Are you sure you're pasting the $smarty->assign('ousers', $ousers); AFTER you created the $ousers object?  The error suggests the variable wasn't an object when you assigned it.

Comment: You need to save that function's response to a variable within smarty.  I've updated my answer to give you a complete solution you can cut and paste.

Comment: If you want additional help, please post the error message you're getting. This code should work, but I cannot see the version of it you're trying to run as it's changed substantially since this question started.

Comment: Please boss visit this page if you can get some idea ... 
http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=85535

Comment: There is no error message but passing of value not successful .. because if i manually type the id of user in php function that's work but i need it from theme file ... with page load (Dynamically)